# TemplateDoesNotExist at /blogapp/reset_password/ path_to/reset_password_email.html

Tags: django, django-urls, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

i am trying to reset password but i got this error TemplateDoesNotExist at /blogapp/reset_password/ path_to/reset_password_email.html

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 
from .views import signupview
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
app_name='blogapp'
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('createblog/',views.blogview,name='blogview'),
    path('blog/',views.blogretrieve,name='blog'),
    path('signup/',views.signupview,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.loginview,name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.logoutview,name='logout'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/',views.authorview,name='author'),
    path('blogdata/<str:pk>/',views.blog,name='blogdata'),
    path('profile/<str:pk>/',views.profile,name='profile'),
    path('change-password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='blogapp/change-password.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('blogapp:password_change_done'))),
    path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='blogapp/password_change_done.html'),name='password_change_done'),
   
    path('reset_password/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='blogapp/reset_password.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('blogapp:password_reset_done'),
            email_template_name='path_to/reset_password_email.html'),name='reset_password'),
    path('reset_password_sent/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='blogapp/reset_password_sent.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view( template_name='blogapp/reset_password_form.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('blogapp:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset_password_complete/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),name='Password_reset_complete'),
    
]
```

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogapp/reset_password/
Template error:

    In template C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\blog\blogapp\templates\blogapp\reset_password_email.html, error at line 6
       Reverse for 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' not found. 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
       1 : {% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
       2 : {% blocktranslate %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktranslate %}
       3 : 
       4 : {% translate "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
       5 : {% block reset_link %}
       6 : {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }} {% url 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %} 
       7 : {% endblock %}
       8 : {% translate 'Your username, in case you’ve forgotten:' %} {{ user.get_username }}
       9 : 
       10 : {% translate "Thanks for using our site!" %}
       11 : 
       12 : {% blocktranslate %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktranslate %}
       13 : 
       14 : {% endautoescape %}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 226, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 144, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 239, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 313, in save
    self.send_mail(
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 256, in send_mail
    body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 176, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 168, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 38, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 56, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 729, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /blogapp/reset_password/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' not found. 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: Are you actually passing the string `path_to/reset_password_email.html` to the view? Did you copy/paste this from somewhere are forget to replace `path_to` with the correct folder name, most likely `blogapp`?

Comment: @IainShelvington but i again got error ,Reverse for 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' not found. 'blogapp/password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern nam

Comment: That's a completely different error, can you post the full traceback for that error from your logs? The name of the urlpattern is `blogapp:password_reset_confirm` but it's not clear where this error is

Comment: You have an error in your `reset_password_email.html` template, the url should have a colon not a slash `{% url 'blogapp:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

Comment: @IainShelvington hey i again got this error Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found. 'password_reset_complete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: You use a capital `P` in your urls.py for that view name, spelling mistake?